# No sound on Fedora 28 XFCE

Tags: fedora, audio, xfce, alsa, alsamixer

After installing Fedora 28 XFCE I had sound (everything worked). I run dnf update and after reboot I have lost sound.

PulseAudio plugin for panel says in tooltip "Not connected to the PulseAudio server".

After clicking it I see "Establishing connection to PulseAudio. Please wait...". Waiting doesn't do anything.

Some other panel plugin for sound control (simpler than previous) just says on tooltip "No valid device and/or element".

Running VLC gives "Audio output failed: The audio device "default" could not be used: Connection refused.".

Running

```
ps aux | grep pulse
```

returns.

Running

```
/usr/lib64/xfce4/panel/wrapper-2.0 /usr/lib64/xfce4/panel/plugins/libpulseaudio-plugin.so 36 14680107 pulseaudio PulseAudio Plugin Adjust the audio volume of the PulseAudio sound system

alsamixer
```

returns

```
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

cannot open mixer: Connection refused
```

Running

```
cat /proc/asound/version
```

returns

```
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k4.17.2-200.fc28.x86_64.
```

Running

```
cat /dev/sndstat
```

returns

```
cat: /dev/sndstat: No such file or directory
```

Running

```
sudo pulseaudio
```

returns

```
W: [pulseaudio] main.c: This program is not intended to be run as root (unless --system is specified).
E: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
```

Running

```
lsusb
```

returns

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0b97:7772 O2 Micro, Inc. OZ776 CCID Smartcard Reader
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0b97:7761 O2 Micro, Inc. Oz776 1.1 Hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04f3:0398 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 029: ID 1017:2010 Speedy Industrial Supplies, Pte., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 1199:9063 Sierra Wireless, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 028: ID 09da:f613 A4Tech Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 031: ID 0fce:51ba Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 0):

Which display manager are you using? I'm using gdm with f30, and when I run

```
ps aux | grep pulse
```

I see

```
gdm       1546  0.0  0.0 976388 12120 ?        Ssl  May07   0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no
me        2271  3.0  0.0 2166196 15396 ?       S<sl May07  73:35 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no
```

Looks like gdm might have a hand in setting up pulse audio. Could try switching to gdm. I think the default display manager is lightdm? There are a boat load of dependencies that will likely come with gdm. Not 100% sure, since I already had the gnome desktop group installed, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on how xfce behaves.